# Using .NET Core MVC Tag/HTML Helpers With Model Object Coming From External Project

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core-mvc, html-helper, tag-helpers

When I use `@model ExternalProject.Model` in my cshtml file and performing stuffs on that model, I keep on getting the below error when loading the page:
`Cannot convert lambda expression to intended delegate type because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type`

Running out of options, I tried making a model internal to this project and it worked. Is it really not possible to use an external DLL for tag helpers?

**External Model Used**

```
public class EmployeeEntity
{
    public EmployeeEntity()
    {
        DailyAttendances = new HashSet<DailyAttendanceEntity>();
        Loans = new HashSet<LoanEntity>();
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get { return FirstName + " " + LastName; } }
    public double TimeInTime { get; set; }
    public string ContactNumber { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public bool IsRegular { get; set; }
    public string Remarks { get; set; }
    public DateTime HireDate { get; set; }
    public int? FingerprintId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<LoanEntity> Loans { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<DailyAttendanceEntity> DailyAttendances { get; set; }
}
```

**Internal Model Used For Testing**

```
public class User
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

**CSHTML file**

```
@using BusinessEntities;
@model EmployeeEntity
<form asp-controller="Demo" asp-action="RegisterInput" method="post">
    FirstName:  <input asp-for="FirstName" /> <br />
    LastName: <input asp-for="LastName" /><br />
    <button type="submit">Register</button>
</form>
```

Edit: This actually also happened while using HTML helpers. Just realized now.

Comment: maybe use a POCO wrapper for external model ? like public class My EmployeeEntity : EmployeeEntity{}

Comment: @federicoscamuzzi I was really hopeful for that solution but unfortunately, it gave the same error.

Comment: are you then put in your cshtml the model MyEmployeeEntity ... not the model EmployeeEntity ... ?

Comment: Yes, that's what I did. Basically created a class (MyEmployeeEntity) as you mentioned, a blank class which just inherits EmployeeEntity. In cshtml, I've changed it to @model MyEmployeeEntity still fails unfortunately.